# QApplication initialization is very slow with mingw

Tags: c++, qt, dll, cmake, qapplication

I having trouble with this code, since **the `QApplication` line takes several seconds** to return:

```
#include <QTime>
#include <QApplication>

#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t2 - t1).count() << " ms" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

With MinGW, the program returns `4702 ms` or something like that everytime (except a crazy `159983 ms` once!).
With Visual Studio, I waited `12 s` the first time, then `0.6 s` the other times, which is acceptable.

I am compiling with Ninja or CMake. What could be the reason of the `QApplication` being so slow to be created and how to speed that up?
Thank you very much for your help.

EDIT: **removing all the unnecessary dll in my directory (opencv_xxx.dll, etc.) solves the problem. But why?** And how to avoid this?

---

*My env: Windows 10, gcc 10.3.0, qt-5.15.1/mingw81_64*

*My compilation output with ninja:*

```
cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\c++.exe -O2 -g -DNDEBUG  -Wl,-rpath,. programs/CMakeFiles/meyeEval.dir/meyeEval.cpp.obj  -o bin\meyeEval.exe -Wl,--out-implib,lib\libmeyeEval.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  D:/Dev/dependances/T5/x64/qt-5.15.1/5.15.1/mingw81_64/lib/libQt5Qml.a D:/Dev/dependances/T5/x64/qt-5.15.1/5.15.1/mingw81_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.a D:/Dev/dependances/T5/x64/qt-5.15.1/5.15.1/mingw81_64/lib/libQt5Network.a D:/Dev/dependances/T5/x64/qt-5.15.1/5.15.1/mingw81_64/lib/libQt5Gui.a D:/Dev/dependances/T5/x64/qt-5.15.1/5.15.1/mingw81_64/lib/libQt5Core.a -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 && cd .
```

Comment: I'm not sure it it is safe to use `QTimer` before `QApplication` is initialized. Use `std::chrono` to take this measurement.

Comment: `removing all the unnecessary dll in my directory (opencv_xxx.dll, etc.) solves the problem. But why?` Qt uses plugins a lot, so probably those dll-s are scanned for additional functionalities.

Comment: did you test timing in `debug` mode? you should test it in `release` mode.

Comment: Thank you. I tested in `Release` and `RelWithDebInfo`, with no change.